# I want to write a method in java that will analyse the string, and get all the message start with # or @ or end with .com

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

```
public static String extract(String text, String reference){
    String hashtag;
    String referenceuser;
    String links;
    String[] temp = text.split("\\s+");
    String result = "";
    //boolean flag = true;
    for(int c = 0 ; c<temp.length ;c++){
        if (temp[c].startsWith("#")){
            hashtag =  "\n" + temp[c];
            result = hashtag;
            return result;
        }
        else if (temp[c].startsWith("@")){
            referenceuser = "\n"+ temp[c];
            result = referenceuser;
            return result;
        }
        else if (temp[c].endsWith(".com")){
            links = temp[c];
            result = links;
            return result;
        }

    }
    return result;
```

I wrote this one, but it seems only find the 1st element i want,  aka the 1st hashtag messages, i was wondering how is that possible to let this code keep looping so that all the matching string is getted. how do I get all the info i needed.

Comment: You are immediately returning if you find a suitable line. If you want all correct lines, you should collect them in an array or in a `List` and return that as a result outside of the loop.

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java

Comment: Yeah like @WonderCsabo said, you don't need to do `return result;` in the `if` statements. Also, if you're looking for the cases where something like #hashtag.com or @user3505187.com happens, you'd put your ".com" `i`f statement in each of the previous two `if` statements. 
Regardless, you should rewrite your code to reflect @gtgaxiola solution.

Comment: Slight criticism: Code like `referenceuser = "\n"+temp[c]; result=referenceuser; return result;` is redundant; it moves data around for no reason.  I'm all for clarity but this doesn't add anything to make it more readable.  If you wanted to return it, just `return "\n" + temp[c];` is good enough.  If you're adding it to a list, then `List.add("\n" + temp[c]);` works.

Comment: I just edited the title based on your code, without realizing the edit might be wrong. To clarify, do you want strings that start with `@`, start with `#`, or end with `.com`; or do you want strings that start with `@` or `#`, _and_ end with `.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple demo

By keeping track of the matches in a `List<String>`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s = "@hello.com\n#howAreyouthisday.com\nhello how are you\n@hellowithnoending";
   String all[] = s.split("\\s+");
   List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
   for(String e : all) {           
       //This regular expression(regex) is looking at the String e
       //to start with either @ or #, as well as end in .com
       if(e.matches("^(@|#).*(\\.com)$")) {
           allMatches.add(e);

       }
   }
   System.out.println("Results:");
   for(String x : allMatches) {
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Outputs

```
Results:
@hello.com
#howAreyouthisday.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Save each string that starts with # or @ into an array. Then loop over this new array and only save the ones that end with .com into a separate array.